# How can I make enumeration class with number shaped String

Tags: java, enums

First, thank you for your help!!

What I want to make with an Enumeration class is a Menu of a restaurant. The menu components have its own id which is number, and name.

```
001("Pasta"),
002("Pizza"),
003("Nuddle"),
004("Steak"),
005("Rice")
```

Above code my first idea but, I got errors, so I thought only String value can be the components of Enumeration. So, I changed the code like below but it generated error again.

```
"001"("Pasta"),
"002"("Pizza"),
"003"("Nuddle"),
"004"("Steak"),
"005"("Rice")
```

The numbers are just IDs of food, so it can have String type. How can I make it?

Comment: I'd swap if to something like `PIZZA("001")` etc. but besides that I feel that a restaurant's menu doesn't really fit an enum. Enums are compile time constants but a restaurant menu is more like runtime data.

Comment: just like variable names,  enum constants cannot start with a number.

Comment: Why do you need the numbers in the enum?

Comment: The reason that I put String in the bracket is that, the name of the menu can be changed more often than the food id. A coffee menu such as Americano can be changed AMERICANO, americano or A.

Comment: Then use AMERICANO("americano"), and change to AMERICANO("a") if you decide to represent Americano by "a" rather than "americano"? Why would you need a number for that?

Comment: I'm practicing with real world situation. For example, a customer of a restaurant can order a food by its name as well as its number on the Menu. Answer from Raphael Roth can be a solution I think..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums names cannot start with numbers. If you want to use Enums, I would suggest to use something like this:

```
public enum Food {
    PASTA("Pasta", 1),
    PIZZA("Pizza", 2);


    /** state variables */
    private String name;
    private int id;

    /** Constructor */
    Food(String name, int id) {
        this.name=name;
        this.id=id;
    }


    /** Accessors */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Comment: If it's just a running number you need, the extra field isn't necessary. You could use the built-in [`Enum.ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) method, e.g. `PASTA.ordinal()`. Ordinals are zero-based so you need to add one to the value if you want the ids to start from 1.

Answer (score 1):

you can use in this way. Or how about add some character like...`F001, F002`

```
public class Tester {

    static enum Food {
        PASTA("001"), PIZZA("002"), NOODLE("003");
        private String number;
        Food(String number){
            this.number = number;
        }
        public String getNumber(){
            return this.number;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( Food.PIZZA.getNumber());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. First create a static map and put number and string value as a key value pair and write a utility to retrieve a food value based on the given number key value after creating your constructor to populate both fields.

```
public enum MenuEnum {

    ONE(1, "Pasta"), TWO(2, "Pizza"), THREE(3, "Noodle");

    private int number;
    private String name;

    private MenuEnum(int number, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getFoodByNumber(int key) {
        return foodMap.get(key) != null ? foodMap.get(key) : null;

    }

    private static final Map<Integer, String> foodMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    static {
        for (MenuEnum val : MenuEnum.values()) {
            foodMap.put(val.getNumber(), val.getName());

        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you make the map a private static variable and initialize it in a static block? Then make getFood a static method too since it doesn't depend on any instance's state.  Also you probably want to make getName and getNumber public too :D

Comment: @muzzlator. That is actually a pretty good advice. I did not pay much attention to it previously. I have made the changes accordingly.